# Getting Dynamic Forms in Angular 2 to get Questions from remote source

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Ok, so actually what I want to do is just get the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html to do what the first TODO in the question.service.ts says.

So really, how do I achieve this: // Todo: get from a remote source of question metadata.

I've been at this for a while and being a beginner at this I have no idea how to go about this. I've tried everything I could think of and still nothing. Please, I would be extremely happy for even the slightest idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is creating a `REST API` on your server side which will give you data, and consume it in Angular Application using `HttpModule`

```
   // questionUrl -> 'api/auestions'

   getQuestions(): Promise<any[]> {
     return this.http.get(this.questionUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data)
   }
```

You may read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I've seen the let questionsUrl = 'api/questions'; but I'm not sure where it should be pointing. It was never described or at least I didn't see it anywhere in the docs. Can you explain it please?

Comment: Also, what if I wanted to mock the backend? Where would my questionUrl point?

Comment: It depends upon what is your background in technology, Different technology .NET, JAVA, PHP, NODE have there way of creating REST API, you have to learn how to write in your respective technology. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answers and will do :-). Cheers!